# Haskel: how to force evaluation of functions and write to a file sequentially?

Tags: haskell, file-io, io, html-parsing, lazy-evaluation

I have a problem with lazy IO in Haskell. Despite reading other questions in that field, I couldn't figure out how to solve my specific case.

I'm using the scalpel package to parse html. The usecase is simple: One site contains links to other sites which describe some kind of event. So I wrote the following structures (I left out some of the implementations here):

```
type Url = String

-- function that parses all urls
allUrls :: Url -> IO (Maybe [Url])

data Event = Event { ... }

-- function that parses an event
parseEvent :: Url -> IO (Maybe Event)

-- function that writes the event to a file
doThings :: Url -> IO ()
doThings url = return url >>= parseEvent >>= (appendFile "/tmp/foo.txt" . show)

-- function that should take all urls and write their events to a file
allEvents :: IO (Maybe [Url]) -> IO (Maybe (IO [()]))
allEvents urls = urls >>= return . liftM (mapM doThings)

-- or alternatively:

-- function that takes all urls and returns all events
allEvents :: IO (Maybe [Url]) -> IO (Maybe (IO [Maybe Event]))
allEvents urls = urls >>= return . liftM (mapM parseEvent)

-- some function that writes all events to a file
allEventsToFile :: IO (Maybe (IO [Maybe Event])) -> IO()
???
```

The doThings function works as expected. Given a url, it parses the corresponding event and writes it to the file. But allEvents does absolutely nothing because of laziness. How can I force the evaluation inside allEvents?

Comment: You need your `allEvents` have type `IO (Maybe [Url]) -> IO ()`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is *not* a problem of lazy IO. Lazy IO is when you read a lazy string from a file, but don't evaluate it – the runtime will in this case defer the actual reading *until* you evaluate it.

The problem is actually that you *don't do any IO* in `allEvents` – you're merely shoving around values in the `IO` *functor*. Those values happen to be `IO` actions themselves, but that doesn't matter. Specifally, `a >>= return . f` is always the same as just `fmap f a`, by the monad laws. And fmapping in IO does not bind actions.

This problem is already observed in the type signature: `-> IO (Maybe (IO [()]))` says that the function yields IO actions that you could then later execute. But in this case, you want to execute everything when you execute `allEvents`. So the signature could be

```
allEvents :: IO (Maybe [Url]) -> IO ()
```

(or perhaps `-> IO (Either EventExecError ())`, if you want to properly handle failure).

This is probably still not what you want: why do you *take* an `IO` action as the argument? That means `allEvents` would itself need to execute that action to first fetch the URLs, before doing any work of its own. That could have its own side-effects and give different results for different calls, do you *want* that?

I guess not, so really it should be

```
allEvents :: Maybe [Url] -> IO ()
```

Now you start out with a plain `Maybe` value, which you can easily pattern-match on:

```
allEvents Nothing = ?  -- perhaps simply `return ()`
allEvents (Just urls) = mapM_ doThings urls
```

To then use that in your program, you need to monadically bind the url-fetching to the event-executing:

```
main :: IO ()
main = do
  urlq <- allUrls
  allEvents urlq
```

...or short `allUrls >>= allEvents`.

Comment: Thanks, this works and is actually also more intuitive and much simpler. I don't know why I didn't come up with this first. Instead of monadically composing the functions I thought just flushing the results of `allUrls` into `allEvents` should be fine. And also I thought it would be ok to build a list of IO actions and then force them to be evaluated.

Comment: That's a really fundamental thing to familiarise in Haskell: evaluating an IO action does _not_ execute it; only monadically binding it to `main` does.